# Getting the right attribute values using Dissolve in QGIS

Tags: attribute-joins, dissolve, sqlite

I have a layer with polygon features with `attribute ZIPcode` and `attribute A`. The `attribute A` can has the `value X` or `NULL`. So there is only one distinct value in the dissolved polygons.

How can I Dissolve the polygon layer with `Zipcode` as `Dissolve field` so that the value of `attribute A` is taken (survives) to the Dissolved layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a Virtual layer to join the attribute A.